# Правка официально-делового стиля

Tags: лексика

Выполните правку текста таким образом, чтобы он соответствовал требованиям официально-делового стиля. Укажите, какой вид правки вы применили.
На основании положения положения о проведении лично-командного первенства муниципального района Янаульский район по национальной борьбе среди МБОУ СОШ, п р и к а з ы в а ю:
*   Освободить от занятий 29 октября 2011 г. для участия в районных соревнованиях по национальной борьбе «КУРЭШ» следующих обучающихся:
Шайдараев игорь Анатольевич - 7г
Бекбатаров Андрей Леонидович - 8а
Саферов Денис Ильич - 8а
Хайнуров Алмаз Владимирович - 7г
Балашов Андрей Маратович - 8а
Нигматуллин Георгий Анисеевич - 11а
     Шакуров Азамат Азатович - 7г
     Шайнуров Артур Альбертович - 8а

Answer (score 1):

Возможен такой вариант:

На основании Положения о проведении лично-командного первенства муниципального района Янаульский по национальной борьбе среди МБОУ СОШ

приказываю:

освободить от занятий 29 октября 2011 г. для участия в районных соревнованиях по национальной борьбе куреш следующих обучающихся:

Шайдараев И. А. (7-г), Бекбатаров А. Л. (8-а), Саферов Д. И. (8-а), Хайнуров А. В. (7-г), Балашов А. М. (8-а), Нигматуллин Г. А. (11-а), Шакуров А. А. (7-г), Шайнуров А. А. (8-а).

Возможен вариант, когда фамилии пишутся не в строчку, а столбиком.

Answer (score 0):

На основании положения положения о проведении лично-командного первенства муниципального района Янаульский район по национальной борьбе среди МБОУ СОШ,

```
              п р и к а з ы в а ю:
```

- Освободить от занятий 29 октября 2011 г. для участия в районных соревнованиях по национальной борьбе «КУРЭШ» следующих обучающихся:

  Шайдараев игорь Анатольевич - 7г

  Бекбатаров Андрей Леонидович - 8а

  Саферов Денис Ильич - 8а

Хайнуров Алмаз Владимирович - 7г

Балашов Андрей Маратович - 8а

Нигматуллин Георгий Анисеевич - 11а

Шакуров Азамат Азатович - 7г

Шайнуров Артур Альбертович - 8а